# emeditor の「強調文字列(1)」の定義の変更

Tags: emeditor

emeditor の「強調文字列(1)」の定義の変更(文字色および背景色)は変更可能でしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

設定のプロパティの `表示` ページで、`指定する部分` 一覧より、`強調文字列(1)` を選択し、`文字色` または `背景色` で `カスタム` を選択して、その右の `...` ボタンをクリックして、色を変更できます。

[image: EmEditor 設定のプロパティ]